# Javascript script button to open window in new tab instead of popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs, popup

I purchased a script online and it has the following javascript code to create a popup window and load a website when you click a button:

```
$('#Browsing').on('click', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      exchange = getCookie('exchange');
      $('#exchange_alert').html('<b style="color: red" ><?php _l("browsing_hint"); ?></b>');
          win = $.popupWindow('<?php _router("browsing"); ?>?start=true', {
          name: 'browsing',
          width: screen.width,
          height: screen.height,
          center: 'screen',
          onLoad: function() {
              if(exchange == 'yes' || exchange == '' || exchange == null)
              {
                setCookie('exchange', 'no');
                browsing(win, '');
                $('#Browsing').hide();
                $('#StopBrowsing').show();
              }
          }
      });
});
```

I am looking for a way to have the button open the window in a new tab instead of a popup. Any help would be very much appreciated. Thank you all very much!

Edit: In the HTML, the button click does this:

```
<a href="javascript::void(0)" id="Browsing" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg"><i class="fa fa-exchange"></i> Clicky <i class="fa fa-exchange"></i></a>
```

Comment: AFAIK the way browsers open a window depends on user preferences, you can't override them. If set to "automatic", you can most likely open a new tab by not passing window parameters to `window.open`.

Answer (score 0):

This #Browsing id was declared in button or href tag in html ?

Comment: javascript:void(0) or #

Comment: I believe in the HREF tag